# convert 4 bytes of data containing both uint & floats to float

Tags: c++

I have an array which has data which is mixed in format. It contains both unsigned ints & floats (all stored in a 4 byte data each).

I want to convert each 4 byte data to a float. However, none of the methods worked for me. For example.

```
union
{
   DWORD i;
   float f;
} u;
```

This method doesn't work. Neither does reinterpret_cast to float.

The data I have is like this.

```
{ 1, 8, 1.00000, -1.000000 }
```

I have a `uint32_t` pointer which points to the memory.

`DWORD value = *(uint_pointer)` gives me the 1, 8 correctly and not the others.
Using a typecast float causes 1.00000 & -1.00000 to be recognized correctly but not the other two.

I basically want the result to be

```
{ 1.00000, 8.00000, 1.00000, -1.00000 }
```

I looked at SO for all the previous answers but none of them worked reliably hence I am posting this again to get some ideas.

Thanks

Comment: Please format your post. You've been here almost two years.

Comment: Also explain the problem further than "it doesn't work"

Comment: Float and int have very different machine representations. Except for some special cases, there is simply no way to determine the type from the bytes, as @s.bandara also pointed out.

Comment: Sorry @LightnessRacesinOrbit. I should have formatted it :(. My mistake. Although I have tried to explain what problem I was running into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know which stretches of 4 bytes are `float`s and which stretches of 4 bytes are `uint`s. If you don't know, there is no way to convert them, unfortunately, they are just 32 bits with ambiguous meaning. However, if you do know that the third value is a `float`, for example, you can obtain it with `float v3 = ((float *)uint_pointer)[3]`. Also, you could check out my lengthy explanation in this previous post: [Granular Synthesis in iOS 6 using AudioFileServices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016259/granular-synthesis-in-ios-6-using-audiofileservices)

**EDIT**:
If you don't know that it is 4 bytes `== sizeof(DWORD) == sizeof(float)` that contain your values, and as a good practice in general, you could cast to `u*` and access it from the union. That way, you use the compiler's knowledge of memory alignment, so `v3 = ((u *)uint_pointer)[3].f` is safer, see comment by @LightnessRacesInOrbit.

Comment: only when `sizeof float == CHAR_BIT*4`

Comment: good one, @LightnessRacesInOrbit, also I should be burnt for not using C++ style casts, I already felt the flames licking...

Comment: Thanks s-bandara. Unfortunately I haven't managed to track down the specs which specify the format of this data. So unless I track that down I won't be able to convert it anyways but that was helpful.